# Reducing duplication of code within two classes that have differing nested classes

Tags: c#, enums, refactoring, xml-serialization

I have two classes (this is C#) that are very similar except they each contain their own nested class and enum.

I would like to refactor them to both inherit from a single abstract class, but I'm running into a problem because the methods are all tightly coupled to the nested class types.

My first plan was to pull out the ItemDetails Class, but it is linked to the ItemType, which is an enum that is specific to each view item class.  Further, I can't just use System.Enum as the type since I need to be able to serialize the details to an xml file.

How could I reduce the duplication within these classes?

```
public class FirstViewItem
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ItemDetails
    {
        public ItemType Type;
        public int Width;
        public string Text;
        public int DisplayOrder;
    }

    public enum ItemType
    {
        None = 0,
        A,
        B,
        C
    }

    public FirstViewItem()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public List<ItemDetails>()
    {
        // code here ...
    }
}

public class SecondViewItem
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ItemDetails
    {
        public ItemType Type;
        public int Width;
        public string Text;
        public int DisplayOrder;
    }

    public enum ItemType
    {
        None = 0,
        X,
        Y,
        X
    }

    public SecondViewItem()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public List<ItemDetails>()
    {
        // code here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably better suited to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: I didn't even know that existed... nice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to make a generic class that is dependent on the item type enum being passed in:

```
public class ViewItem<T>
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ItemDetails
    {
        public T Type; // the generic type is inserted here
        public int Width;
        public string Text;
        public int DisplayOrder;
    }

    // common code that uses ItemDetails
}
```

Then some item types:

```
public enum FirstItemType
{
    None = 0,
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public enum SecondItemType
{
    None = 0,
    X,
    Y,
    Z
}
```

Then usage:

```
var firstViewItem = new ViewItem<FirstItemType>();
```

Comment: I kept separate classes, but modified the generic class as you've shown to also be abstract and inherited from it.

Answer (score 2):

Yamen's answer is good.

I'd started writing this so i'll finish. Here's an example of using generics with a base class and some inheriting classes:

```
public class BaseClass<T>
{
   public T NestedClass{get;set;}
}

public  class MainOne : BaseClass<MainOneType>
{
}

public class MainTwo : BaseClass<MainTwoType>
{
}

public class MainOneType
{
}

public class MainTwoType
{
}
```

Comment: +1, these are good examples that are probably very relevant to the original question.

Comment: I ended up going with a combination of this and what @yamen had.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using ideas from 2 different answers, so I'll answer with the combined result.

```
public class BaseViewItem<T> where T : struct
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ItemDetails
    {
        public T Type;
        public int Width;
        public string Text;
        public int DisplayOrder;
    }

    public FirstViewItem()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public List<ItemDetails>()
    {
        // code here ...
    }
}

public class FirstViewItem : BaseViewItem<FirstItemType>
{
    // class-specific code...
}

public class SecondViewItem : BaseViewItem<SecondItemType>
{
    // class-specific code...
}

public enum FirstItemType
{
    None = 0, A, B, C
}

public enum SecondItemType
{
    None = 0, X, Y, Z
}
```